# create a new array by comparing if an ID exists on another array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to extract only the products in the array of objects with a product ID that exists in the masterAccessories list array which comes from a specific product that has a list of related_products in an array form.

**JSON Example:**

```
{"product":
        {
            "id": 3,
            "product_name": "Product Name",
            "sku": "sku_ID",
            "description": "description",
            "product_link": "link",
            "cat_id": "cat-ID",
            "cat_name": "Cat Name",
            "related_products": [5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54]
        }
    },
    {"product":
        {
            "id": 4,
            "product_name": "product_name",
            "sku": "sku_id",
            "description": "description",
            "product_link": "link",
            "cat_id": "cat-tc",
            "cat_name": "Cat Name",
            "related_products": []
        }
    },
```

I am basically trying to find all the products with the id that exists in the related prodcuts array.

**Related Products Array:**

```
[5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54]
```

**My Attempt so far with no luck:**

```
myPromise.then(function (result) {
        let products = JSON.parse(result);
        return products;
    }, function (result) {
        console.error(result);
    }).then(function(products){
        let productArray = products[0].products;
        masterProduct += -1;
        let accesoriesList = Object.values(productArray)[masterProduct];
        let masterAccessories = accesoriesList.product.related_products;
        console.log('Master: ',masterAccessories);
        var newArray = [];
        for(let i=0;i<productArray.length;i++){
            if(masterAccessories.indexOf(productArray[i].product.id) === -1){
                newArray.push(productArray[i]);
            }
        }
        console.log('NewArray: ',newArray);
        return accesoriesList;
    })//just another then() that returns true
```

Here is one of the objects that gets returned from the productArray variable from console if it helps:

```
1:product:{id: 2, product_name: "Product Name", sku: "SkuID", description: "Description", product_link: "link", …} __proto__:Object
```

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that from all the products you want to get only those whose ID is in the array of related products of any of the products?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to say not equal to -1 instead of equal to 1.

Problem area:

```
for(let i=0;i<productArray.length;i++){
    if(masterAccessories.indexOf(productArray[i].product.id) === -1){
        newArray.push(productArray[i]);
    }
    console.log(productArray[i].product.id);
}
```

Answer:

```
for(let i=0;i<productArray.length;i++){
    if(masterAccessories.indexOf(productArray[i].product.id) !== -1){
        newArray.push(productArray[i]);
    }
    console.log(productArray[i].product.id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery:

```
    var products = json;//<your product json array deserialized>;

    var ids = [5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54];

    var productsContainedArray = $.grep(products, function (prod) {
        return ids.indexOf(prod.product.id) != -1;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this meets your expectations for the desired result.

```js
const
  products = [ 
    {
      productId: 1,
      name: 'A',
      relatedProducts: [2]
    },
    {
      productId: 2,
      name: 'B',
      relatedProducts: [1, 3]
    },
    {
      productId: 3,
      name: 'C',
      relatedProducts: []
    },
    {
      productId: 4,
      name: 'D',
      relatedProducts: [1]
    }
  ];
  
function getReferencedProducts(input) {
  let
    referencedProducts = new Set();

  // Iterate over all the products and create a set with the IDs of all 
  // referenced products. Each product ID will appear only once in the set.
  input.forEach(product => {
    // Create a new set based on the current set and the related products of 
    // the current product.
    referencedProducts = new Set([...referencedProducts, ...product.relatedProducts]);  
  });
  
  // Filter the products to only return those products whose ID is in
  // the set of referenced products.
  return input.filter(product => referencedProducts.has(product.productId)); 
}

// This should output products 1, 2, 3 as product is never referenced.
console.log(getReferencedProducts(products));
```